# SQL table structure for store value against list of combination

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a requirement from client where I need to store a value against list of combination.

For example I have following LOBs and against each combination I need to store a value.

1. Auto
2. WC
3. Personal

I purposed multiple solutions he is not satisfied with anyone.

Solution 1: create single table, insert value against all possible combination(string) something like

```
LOB Value
Auto    1
WC  2
Personal    3
Auto,WC 4
Auto, personal  5
WC, Personal    6
Auto, WC, Personal  7
```

Solution 2: create lkp_lob, lob_group and lob_group_detail tables. Each group combination represent a group.
 Lkp_lob

```
Lob_key Name
1   Auto
2   WC
3   Person
```

Lob_group (unique query constrain on lob_group_key and lob_key)

```
Lob_group_key   Lob_key
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   1
4   2
5   1
5   3
6   2
6   3
7   1
7   2
7   3
```

Lob_group_detail

```
Lob_group_key   Value
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is an LOB?  Combinations of what?  What is WC (the abbreviation commonly means "water closet", a synonym for toilet)?
 What are the criticisms of the approaches?  What database are you using (please tag the question)?  What do the values represent?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I did not understood that terms you said. 
But from database perspective it is always good to have multiple tables for each module. You will be facing less difficulties when doing CRUD. And will be more faster.